WKWebView login session remains active when app is killed and relaunched
I am facing a weird issue in iOS app using WKWebView and this is happening in device but not simulator. We have a button on click of which we are creating a new WKWebView instance and before loading the login url we are clearing website data using WKWebsiteDataStore removeDataOfTypes method to remove allWebsiteDataTypes.
This code ends the session when app is run normally that is we install and launch and click on the button and we get the login page. The problem is arising when we kill the app from background and relaunch it. This time when we click on the same button the session remains active.
I am not sure what is happening here. Any suggestion, info or way to debug is really appreciated. Thanks!
